# How to merge two dataframes on two variables - the first an exact match on factor variable, the second a fuzzy match for numeric variable

Tags: r, fuzzyjoin

#### Here are the dataframes (do not edit this portion)

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
id <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 5)
score <- sample(1:50, 15)
label <- paste(sample(LETTERS, 15 * 5, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
label <- substring(label, seq(1, 71, by = 5), seq(5, 75, by = 5))
df1 <- data.frame(id, score, label)
df1 <- df1[order(df1$id, df1$score), ]
row.names(df1) <- 1:nrow(df1)
df1

   id score label
1   A     3 JMGII
2   A    14 KGULO
3   A    15 ISDNQ
4   A    31 CHZGJ
5   A    42 JWUGU
6   B    25 OZPTF
7   B    26 KHVVG
8   B    37 LMRAY
9   B    43 FYBEH
10  B    48 YFUOI
11  C     5 BDMEV
12  C     9 PLYNC
13  C    27 PQVRQ
14  C    28 NYWCH
15  C    40 SYTVY

id <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3)
score <- sample(1:50, 9)
df2 <- data.frame(id, score)
df2 <- df2[order(df2$id, df2$score), ]
df2 <- df2 %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(order = row_number())
row.names(df2) <- 1:nrow(df2)
df2

# A tibble: 9 × 3
# Groups:   id [3]
  id    score order
* <chr> <int> <int>
1 A        14     1
2 A        29     2
3 A        32     3
4 B         3     1
5 B         7     2
6 B        23     3
7 C        15     1
8 C        21     2
9 C        37     3
```

I have two identically named columns in two dataframes (df1 and df2).

1st column is 'ID' a factor variable.
2nd column is 'score' a numeric variable.

I want to do an inner join on two conditions: 1) match on ID exactly, 2) for each score on *df2* join all observations that have the closest score on *df1* (to a difference limit of **5**) for that ID.

For the 2nd condition, this means that for each row of *df2* it should join with rows of *df1* with the lowest difference in score to it, up till a difference of 5.

> Example: For the first row of *df2*, it should only join with row 2 of *df1* (difference of 0 as both are 14), and not join row 3 of *df1* (difference of 1).

Notes:

> I tried various packages like fuzzyjoin, but I can't seem to implement
> the fuzzy match portion simultaneously, with max_dist = 2,
> distance_col = "distance".
>
> I've scoured through stackoverflow solutions for similar topics, but
> none worked so far - they didn't have the same mix of 1 numeric fuzzy
> and 1 factor exact either..

Comment: Maybe try a `full_join(by = ID)`, then `group_by(ID)` `filter(score_x <= score_y + 2 & score_x >= score_y - 2)` and `slice_max(n=1)`? It's hard to know what will work without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make this question easier to answer.

Comment: Hi, I've now added the reproducible example.
I can't use slice_max(n=1) for this case as there can be multiple observations with the same difference in score, and I would need all of those.

Comment: Thanks for adding the the reproducible example @user22746157; I posted an answer but if i've misunderstood your expected outcome, please leave a comment and I'll fix it

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

Thanks for providing example data and more details.

I still think that `dplyr::join_by` is useful here: we can specify that `df2$score` lies between `df1$score` +/- 5.

I don't know if the minimum difference in scores can be specified as part of the join, but it can be calculated after the join using a `filter`.

```
library(dplyr)


df1 %>% 
  mutate(score_lower = score - 5, 
         score_upper = score + 5) %>% 
  inner_join(df2, 
             by = join_by(id, between(y$score, x$score_lower, x$score_upper))) %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
filter(abs(score.x - score.y) == min(abs(score.x - score.y))) %>% 
ungroup()
```

Result, retaining all columns to show that the join worked as expected. You could add a `dplyr::select` to the end of the code to retain and/or rename the desired columns.

```
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  id    score.x label score_lower score_upper score.y order
  <chr>   <int> <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>   <int> <int>
1 A          14 KGULO           9          19      14     1
2 B          25 OZPTF          20          30      23     3
3 C          40 SYTVY          35          45      37     3
```

Comment: Hi, I've now added the example data.

Thanks but I would need not all the observations between the difference range, but only those with the smallest difference in scores for each ID.

Comment: OK, answer edited to reflect the new information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've misunderstood your desired outcome, but here's a potential solution:

Example data:

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
id <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 5)
score <- sample(1:50, 15)
label <- paste(sample(LETTERS, 15 * 5, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
label <- substring(label, seq(1, 71, by = 5), seq(5, 75, by = 5))
df1 <- data.frame(id, score, label)
df1 <- df1[order(df1$id, df1$score), ]
row.names(df1) <- 1:nrow(df1)
df1
#>    id score label
#> 1   A     3 JMGII
#> 2   A    14 KGULO
#> 3   A    15 ISDNQ
#> 4   A    31 CHZGJ
#> 5   A    42 JWUGU
#> 6   B    25 OZPTF
#> 7   B    26 KHVVG
#> 8   B    37 LMRAY
#> 9   B    43 FYBEH
#> 10  B    48 YFUOI
#> 11  C     5 BDMEV
#> 12  C     9 PLYNC
#> 13  C    27 PQVRQ
#> 14  C    28 NYWCH
#> 15  C    40 SYTVY

id <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3)
score <- sample(1:50, 9)
df2 <- data.frame(id, score)
df2 <- df2[order(df2$id, df2$score), ]
df2 <- df2 %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(order = row_number())
row.names(df2) <- 1:nrow(df2)
#> Warning: Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated.
df2
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>   id    score order
#> * <chr> <int> <int>
#> 1 A        14     1
#> 2 A        29     2
#> 3 A        32     3
#> 4 B         3     1
#> 5 B         7     2
#> 6 B        23     3
#> 7 C        15     1
#> 8 C        21     2
#> 9 C        37     3
```

---

Potential solution:

```r
df1 %>%
  full_join(df2, by = join_by(id), relationship = "many-to-many") %>%
  group_by(id, score.y) %>%
  filter(abs(score.y - score.x) <= 5 & 
           abs(score.y - score.x) == min(abs(score.y - score.x)))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#> # Groups:   id, score.y [5]
#>   id    score.x label score.y order
#>   <chr>   <int> <chr>   <int> <int>
#> 1 A          14 KGULO      14     1
#> 2 A          31 CHZGJ      29     2
#> 3 A          31 CHZGJ      32     3
#> 4 B          25 OZPTF      23     3
#> 5 C          40 SYTVY      37     3
```

---

In the example df2$score == 29 'matches' with df1$score == 31; add the value df1$score == 27 to the dataframe (show that values the same distance from df2$score are both retained):

```r
df1[5,2] <- 27

df1 %>%
  full_join(df2, by = join_by(id), relationship = "many-to-many") %>%
  group_by(id, score.y) %>%
  filter(abs(score.y - score.x) <= 5 & 
           abs(score.y - score.x) == min(abs(score.y - score.x)))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#> # Groups:   id, score.y [5]
#>   id    score.x label score.y order
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>   <int> <int>
#> 1 A          14 KGULO      14     1
#> 2 A          31 CHZGJ      29     2
#> 3 A          31 CHZGJ      32     3
#> 4 A          27 JWUGU      29     2
#> 5 B          25 OZPTF      23     3
#> 6 C          40 SYTVY      37     3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>